# EJS conditional IF

Tags: ejs

newbie to EJS here,

Tried to get data from MongoDB and display in view. If there is no data, display "otherCondition", if there is data, do loop and display "repeat" and "unrelated"

```
 <% if (typeof eventData == 'object'){ %> // check if its empty/undefined
     <% eventData.forEach(function(event) { %> // loop if exists
         <div class="repeat">
            ...                           // other code
         </div>
     <% }) %>                             // end of loop
     <div class="unrelated">                  
            ...                           // other code (again)
     </div>
 <% } else { %>                           // else condition
     <div class="otherCondition">                  
            ...                           // other code (again)
     </div>
 <% } %>
```

EJS code above, route code below:

```
router.route('/').get(function(req, res, next) {
        mongoose.model('Event').find({}, function(err, events) {
            if (err) {
                return console.error(err);
            } else {
                res.format({
                    html: function() {
                        res.render('events', {
                            eventData: events,
                            user: req.user,
                        });
                        if (typeof eventData == 'object')
                            console.log('display new events: ' + eventData);
                        else
                            console.log('no events, sorry :(');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    })
```

Probably another silly question, but can anyone help me how to fix this? In console, I get `no events, sorry :(` but my  `<div class="otherCondition"></div>`  doesn't get displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here eventData is always an Array, Because in server side your using query is **find()** method,
So **typeof eventData will always return an object** hence your first condition is always true so the controller never goto otherCondition.

Better you check the lenth of eventData in first if condition

```js
<% if(constructor.eventData === Array && eventData.length > 0){ %>
   <% eventData.forEach(function(event) { %> // loop if exists
     <div class="repeat">
        ...                           // other code
     </div>
   <% }) %>                             // end of loop
   <div class="unrelated">                  
        ...                           // other code (again)
   </div>
<% }else{ %>
   <div class="otherCondition">                  
        ...                           // other code (again)
   </div>
<% } %>
```